# Wierd structure of many clauses

Tags: sentence-structure

> Rep. Jason Smith, the House’s new top tax writer, is promoting an approach he says would favor
> working-class Americans over large corporations, a shift in tone from his predecessors
> that raises questions about companies’ ability to push tax cuts through Congress.

It is from [the Wall Street Journal.](https://www.wsj.com/articles/top-gop-tax-legislator-says-hell-boost-workers-probe-companies-11675695374?st=9b6073ohg8ep8b1&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink)

I understand the passage as he is promoting an approach (and) he says (that the approach) would favor ...

If so, how can 'and' and 'that the approach' be omitted? If not so, how can I disassemble the passage to simpler parts to correctly understand?

Lastly, is it  a usual expression?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are parsing the sentence very slightly incorrectly.  It isn't exactly that he is promoting an approach, **and** he says the approach would favor working-class Americans; rather, he is promoting an approach *that* he says would favor working-class Americans.

The entire thing is kind of an example of deleting *which is* and *that* - "...an approach *that* he says would favor...*which is* a shift in tone..."

References:
https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/when-to-delete-that/
https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info

Comment: I guessed it and I know when I can omit a relative pronoun. In that case I could not figure out what the subject of 'would' is. 'An approach' would not be the subject because it is the object of 'promote'. Thanks.